# Remove 15 rep limit on voting up answers to the owners questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, asking-questions, up-votes

Shouldn't the question owner be able to vote up answers to his/her own question?

I understand that this is rather edge case (since it probably only affects a user's first question), but I had it come up in [a recent question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108348/xslt-deepening-content-structure/2108434#2108434).

Comment: Anyone care to explain their downvotes? 5 downvotes and no comment is pathetic.

Comment: On Meta, downvotes don't mean that people think your question is poorly written, downvotes mean that we disagree with your idea.

Answer (score 5):

Doing so would create a massive rep-farming exploit system.

Comment: How so? (Not challenging, just genuinely curious. I'd imagine even sock puppets can hit 15 rep in a day, especially if the corresponding "real" account upvotes them into it.)

Comment: I think that 15 rep limit would still be an issue because you'd have to think of one good question or answer. If you can do that then the user will hit 15 rep on his *first* question, so no sock puppets are needed. Bots are unlikely to think of a question themselves. This system is not waterproof of course; but then again, it just needs to float.